# Calling a RESTful API Iteratively

Tags: java, spring

I am building an orchestration service layer that calls multiple 3rd party RESTful Api's. One of the Api's require for me to call it multiple times at certain intervals until I get a value of "finished" for "status".

Language: Java
IDE: STS
Application Framework: Spring

Requirements:
Call at 30 second intervals
If combined interval reaches or passes 5 minutes, then fail.

Json:

When I need to call it again

```
{
   "id": 1234,
   "status":"pending
}
```

When I know it is finished

```
{
   "id":1234,
   "status": "finished"
}
```

Is there a package or some way that I can achieve this without using a while loop and Thead.sleep()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) for this where one task is calling REST with interval 30 seconds and the second task is canceling the first one after 5 minutes. Example on Java 8:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
ScheduledFuture<?> task = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    () -> System.out.println("some task"), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    System.out.println("shutdown");
    task.cancel(false);
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

When you get `finished` message you can also cancel all tasks via `task.cancel(false);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try @Scheduled Spring annotation. For example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRate()
{
    logger.info("Executed");
}
```

Spring way of implementing your scenario would be: 
1) add bean to your Spring application java config

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler()
{
    return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
}
```

2) autowire taskScheduler in your class:

```
@Autowired ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler
```

3) use taskScheduler in your class using the following code:

```
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("running"), 30*1000);

    taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
        System.out.println("finish");
        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*60*1000));
```

The idea is to schedule task execution every 30 seconds and to cancel it using another task, which will be run in 5 minutes once. Good thing here is that this taskScheduler is managed by Spring.